# Julia HCubature.jl limits dependinding on other variables

Tags: julia, integration

I want to calculate double integral with HCubature, but one of the variables' limit depends on the other. For example:
[image]

And I've tried primitively:

```
using HCubature
F(x, y) = x+y
hcubature(r->F(r[1], r[2]), [0,0], [r[2], 1])
```

and of course it doesn't work and gives an error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: r not defined
```

How can I calculate such integral? Maybe using another package? If so, which package and how to do this?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You can use the package **SimplicialCubature** or **PolyhedralCubature**.

Comment: Does PolyhedralCubature package allows calculating integrals of only 3 variables?

Comment: The number of variables you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is an iterated integral. `hcubature` can be used to calculate the integrals from the inside out, like so:

```
julia> F(x, y) = x+y
F (generic function with 1 method)

julia> hcubature(r->hcubature(s->F(s[1],r[1]), [0], [r[1]])[1], [0], [1])
(0.4999999999999999, 1.1102230246251565e-16)
```

So the answer is `0.5`. In case the semantics is unclear, the integration is over a triangle (0,0)-(1,0)-(1,1). The function ranges from 0 to 2 on this triangle and so the answer is reasonable.

Comment: Thank you! So there is no option to calculate it using just one hcubature? Is hcubature in this case the most efficient?

Comment: The simple answer is I don't know. See the comment on the question post for another option to explore. There should be better method in theory.

Answer (score -1):

Use a change of variables: see the links [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-compute-the-integration-of-the-following-formula-by-hcubature/32269)